# pattern annotation doesn't generate on int64 swagger using open api generator

Tags: java, swagger, openapi-generator

I'm using swagger 2 and open api 5.3.1 generator to generate some classes. Currently, it does not seem to be generating a pattern annotation on Long(defined as int64 in swagger). How can I do this?

swagger:

```
id:
 type: integer
 format: int64
 pattern: '^\d{16,19}$'
 minLength: 16
 maxLength: 19
```

code generated

```
  @javax.annotation.Nonnull
  @NotNull
  @ApiModelProperty( required = true, )
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_ID)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
```

Comment: `pattern`, `minLength` and `maxLength` are string-specific keywords. They don't apply to numbers. Numbers only have [`minimum` and `maximum`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#range).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The pattern keyword lets you define a regular expression template for
the string value**

It does not support Integer/Long

---

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern

The documentation states:

> The pattern keyword lets you define a regular expression template for
> the string value. Only the values that match this template will be
> accepted. The regular expression syntax used is from JavaScript (more
> specifically, ECMA 262). Regular expressions are case-sensitive, that
> is, [a-z] and [A-Z] are different expressions. For example, the
> following pattern matches a Social Security Number (SSN) in the
> 123-45-6789 format:

```
ssn:
  type: string
  pattern: '^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$'
```

> Note that the regular expression is enclosed in the ^…$ tokens, where
> ^ means the beginning of the string, and $ means the end of the
> string. Without ^…$, pattern works as a partial match, that is,
> matches any string that contains the specified regular expression. For
> example, pattern: pet matches pet, petstore and carpet. The ^…$ token
> forces an exact match.

For the datatype integer, it will look like:

```
    type: integer
    format: int64
    minimum: -86400
    maximum: 86400
```

**To clarify minimum/maximum:**

Minimum and Maximum
Use the minimum and maximum keywords to specify the range of possible values:

```
type: integer
minimum: 1
maximum: 20
```

By default, the minimum and maximum values are included in the range, that is:

```
minimum ≤ value ≤ maximum
```

> To exclude the boundary values, specify exclusiveMinimum: true and
> exclusiveMaximum: true. For example, you can define a floating-point
> number range as 0–50 and exclude the 0 value:

```
type: number
minimum: 0
exclusiveMinimum: true
maximum: 50
```

> The word “exclusive” in exclusiveMinimum and exclusiveMaximum means
> the corresponding boundary is excluded: Keyword   Description
> exclusiveMinimum: false or not included   value ≥ minimum
> exclusiveMinimum: true    value > minimum exclusiveMaximum: false or not
> included  value ≤ maximum exclusiveMaximum: true  value < maximum

Comment: so how can I enforce validation on an integer?

Comment: In my case I would like to validate by lenght i.e between say 12 and 14 digits. Looks that is not directly possible unless I specify something like  `min: 111111111111` `max:99999999999999`

Comment: The notion of length is "String" related.  Numbers match ` <= and =>`